# Multiple keyboard layouts when logging in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, keyboard-layout, login-screen

I'm currently using my Outlook credentials when logging in to my Windows 8.1 Laptop installation. When I start up the laptop, I'm greeted with the welcome screen which has two drop down options at the bottom right:

1. ENG (USA Keyboard layout)
2. ENG (UK keyboard layout)

My main/primary keyboard layout is USA so not sure why the drop down shows two of them. To make things worse, the default selected layout is UK so every time I log in, I have to change the layout manually and then log in.

Is there a way of making sure that only USA keyboard layout is used by default or at least the USA one is selected by default?

TIA,
sasuke

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows 7 but i think it's the same in Windows 8.1.
Right click on the Language bar -> Settings...  -> Default input language -> English (United States).
You can also remove your UK keyboard from Text Services and Input Languages. Go to Control panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages -> Change keyboards...

Comment: Thanks, but I just have 1 input language configured, not sure where the UK one comes from...http://imgur.com/xISeFxS